# Should i send the needed id in the params or as property in the request object?

Tags: node.js

I have a post request where for the needed logic i need to send some id on that post request.

What is better option, to get that as id on the back end

```
app.post('/:id', (req, res) => {
    
})
```

or to take that id from the expected obj, delete is and post the object

```
app.post('', (req, res) => {
    let obj =  req.body;
    let id = obj.id;
    delete obj.id;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use body for post, patch and put. You can send more diverse data in post body than url. You should params with get or delete request.

Answer (score 0):

Sending ID in params would increase readability of your API for sure. For example, if your API is updating an user by ID then your route will be as follows:

To update user: `app.put('/user/:id', (req, res) => {})`

From above routes we can say that this particular API is updating some data of a particular user using the ID sent in params, yeah but sending ID alone would not make sense in terms of readability.

To add new user: `app.post('/user',(req, res) => {})`